# How to remove all imageDisplayEvent listeners

Tags: dm-script

I can set up one or more event listeners this way:

```
number roiListener1=imgDsp.ImageDisplayAddEventListener("roi_changed:ROI_Changed1")
number roiListener2=imgDsp.ImageDisplayAddEventListener("roi_changed:ROI_Changed2")
```

To remove them, I would do this:

```
imgDsp.ImageDisplayRemoveEventListener(roiListener1)
imgDsp.ImageDisplayRemoveEventListener(roiListener2)
```

Is there a way to remove all existing listeners attached on an imageDisplay, without giving the listener variable names? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Good question, but no, there isn't.

Except, of course, if the imageDisplay itself gets destroyed, which will remove the linked listeneres automatically, unless they themselves are "held" in memory due to something else (like a member-variable image which is displayed, another listener etc.)

The easiest way to "deal" with listeners is to manage the IDs in a TagList, then one can simply iterate over all entries.

Comment: Thanks BmyGuest. Very good advice. It solves the annoying lingering listeners problem.

Comment: @user6406828 Glad I could help. If the post "answers" your question, please be so kind and "accept" it by clicking the check on the left side. This marks the question "solved" in the database.